# Getting Timing and Location Information for Two Simultaneous Screen Interactions in Flutter

Tags: flutter

My aim is to capture both timing information and location information for two "simultaneous" (possibly within a millisecond of each other) interactions with the screen. Imagine trying to capture timing and location information for someone pressing two spots on the screen with two fingers, one from each hand.

It would be enough to create two buttons on the screen that, when pressed (*), record the epoch timestamp in microseconds (e.g., using [microsecondsSinceEpoch](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-core/DateTime/microsecondsSinceEpoch.html) in the appropriate callback method) and the [global] coordinates of the screen interaction.

It is straightforward enough to do exactly one of these, as the snippet below shows. Unfortunately, the `MaterialButton` implementation does not offer location information and the `GestureDetector` implementation misses near-simultaneous interactions (e.g., it captures only one interaction of two interactions if the interactions are sufficiently near in time).

Is my usage of `GestureDetector` flawed? Is there a mechanism to determine where a `MaterialButton` is pressed? Is some other implementation the best solution?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String debug = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Simultaneous Tap Example',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget> [
            Text(debug),
            // The MaterialButton implementation provides timing information for
            // simultaneous clicks, though lacks location information.
            Row(
              children: <Widget> [
                MaterialButton(
                  child: Text('Left Material Button'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      print('left material button press');
                      debug += 'left material button; ';
                    });
                  },
                  height: 100,
                  minWidth: 100,
                ),
                MaterialButton(
                  child: Text('Right Material Button'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      print('right material button press');
                      debug += 'right material button; ';
                    });
                  },
                  height: 100,
                  minWidth: 100,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            // The GestureDetector implementation provides location information,
            // though fails to properly capture simultaneous clicks.
            Row(
              children: <Widget> [
                GestureDetector(
                  behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
                  onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) {
                    setState(() {
                      print(details.globalPosition.toString());
                      debug += '${details.globalPosition}; ';
                    });
                  },
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget> [
                      Container(
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[Text('Left Container')],
                        ),
                        height: 100,
                        width: 100,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[Text('Right Container')],
                        ),
                        height: 100,
                        width: 100,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

(*) There is some flexibility on what this means, i.e., both of tap down and force press peak would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

By using two `GestureDetectors`, each one scoped to one `Container`, I was able to get simultaneous taps captured (i.e., both `onTapDown` methods to trigger) when the container buttons were pressed simultaneously.